# Django view: Count specific value from model

Tags: python, django, django-views

In a django view I have:

```
 signed_by = Demographic.objects.all().values_list('data_entered_by')
```

And I get `[(u'Patient',),(u'Patient',), (u'Other',)]`.

I want to count all that have `Patient` value and all that have `Other` value respectively.

In case I use

```
signed_by.count()
```

I get the count for all. How do I count a specified value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) the queryset:

```
signed_by = Demographic.objects.values('data_entered_by').annotate(cnt=Count('id'))
```

As a result you can get count for each `data_entered_by` value as follows, since it return a list of dict object:

```
for q in signed_by:
    print(q['data_entered_by'], q['cnt])
```

---

From the documentation:

> When an `annotate()` clause is specified, each object in the `QuerySet` will be annotated with the specified values.

Comment: What is the meaning of the annotate()?

Comment: I want to get a number for each.

Comment: I added what annotate does. It is used to annotate each object in a queryset with certain computed fields. I don't understand this part from your comments though ... _I want to get a number for each_ ?

Comment: And I case I want to print the `cnt` value for each of them, how will I do it?

Comment: I updated the answer so demonstrate how you can access the count.

Comment: OK, great! Thanks! You answer is really helpful!